Duplicates Found in CBC
Pyomo generated this CBC file, which CBC says is not valid because contains duplicates. How to found these duplicates?
Solver command line: ['/usr/bin/cbc', '-printingOptions', 'all', '-import', '/tmp/tmpsmfui9oj.pyomo.lp', '-stat=1', '-solve', '-solu', '/tmp/tmpsmfui9oj.pyomo.soln']

Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Mar 24 2020 

command line - /usr/bin/cbc -printingOptions all -import /tmp/tmpsmfui9oj.pyomo.lp -stat=1 -solve -solu /tmp/tmpsmfui9oj.pyomo.soln (default strategy 1)
Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
### ERROR: 4 duplicates in objective

### ERROR: 4 duplicates in objective and matrix

ERROR: CoinLpIO::readLp, ### ERROR: 4 duplicates in objective and matrix

There were -1 errors on input
** Current model not valid
** Current model not valid
** Current model not valid
No match for /tmp/tmpsmfui9oj.pyomo.soln - ? for list of commands
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00






Can you provide also the objective in the question?
